# Google places API Platform - intercept the call

Tags: android, api, autocomplete, google-places-api

I wish to use the Google Places SDK for Android, to autocomplete the address inserted by user, but I wish to redirect all calls to our API platform.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: at that point, what are you really using the google places api for ?

Comment: We want to get a destination address informed by user.